# integrate tus-node-server into feathersjs with express

Tags: node.js, express, feathersjs, fileserver, feathers-hook

I have an existing and properly working Feathers project is in the most recent feathers cli ("Buzzard") structure. Now I am trying add [tus-node-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tus-node-server) as upload server. As you can find in the link their instructions to set it up as express middleware are as follows:

```
const tus = require('tus-node-server');
const server = new tus.Server();
server.datastore = new tus.FileStore({
    path: '/files'
});

var app = express();
const uploadApp = express();
uploadApp.all('*', server.handle.bind(server));
app.use('/uploads', uploadApp);
app.listen(port, host);
```

Following these instructions I tried adding this to my app.js file:

```
// tus node server
const tus = require('tus-node-server');
const tusServer = new tus.Server();
tusServer.datastore = new tus.FileStore({
  path: '../uploads'
});

const uploadApp = express();
uploadApp.all('*', tusServer.handle.bind(tusServer));
app.use('/uploads', uploadApp);
```

For completeness I give the entire app.js file:

```
const path = require('path');
const favicon = require('serve-favicon');
const compress = require('compression');
const cors = require('cors');
const helmet = require('helmet');
const logger = require('winston');

const feathers = require('@feathersjs/feathers');
const configuration = require('@feathersjs/configuration');
const express = require('@feathersjs/express');
const socketio = require('@feathersjs/socketio');

const middleware = require('./middleware');
const services = require('./services');
const appHooks = require('./app.hooks');
const channels = require('./channels');

const sequelize = require('./sequelize');

const authentication = require('./authentication');

const app = express(feathers());

// Load app configuration
app.configure(configuration());
// Enable CORS, security, compression, favicon and body parsing
app.use(cors());
app.use(helmet());
app.use(compress());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(favicon(path.join(app.get('public'), 'favicon.ico')));

// Host the public folder
app.use('/', express.static(app.get('public')));

// Set up Plugins and providers
app.configure(express.rest());
app.configure(socketio({
  wsEngine: 'uws',
  timeout: 120000
}));
app.configure(sequelize);

// Configure other middleware (see `middleware/index.js`)
app.configure(middleware);
app.configure(authentication);
// Set up our services (see `services/index.js`)
app.configure(services);
// Set up event channels (see channels.js)
app.configure(channels);

// tus node server
const tus = require('tus-node-server');
const tusServer = new tus.Server();
tusServer.datastore = new tus.FileStore({
  path: '../uploads'
});

const uploadApp = express();
uploadApp.all('*', tusServer.handle.bind(tusServer));
app.use('/uploads', uploadApp);

// Configure a middleware for 404s and the error handler
app.use(express.notFound());
app.use(express.errorHandler({ logger }));

app.hooks(appHooks);

module.exports = app;
```

I get this error:

```
# npm start

> api_server@0.0.0 start /home/usr/api_server
> node src/

/home/usr/api_server/node_modules/@feathersjs/express/lib/index.js:11
    throw new Error('@feathersjs/express requires a valid Feathers application instance');
    ^

Error: @feathersjs/express requires a valid Feathers application instance
    at feathersExpress (/home/usr/api_server/node_modules/@feathersjs/express/lib/index.js:11:11)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/usr/api_server/src/app.js:70:19)
    at Module._compile (module.js:660:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:671:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:573:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:513:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:505:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:604:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/usr/api_server/src/index.js:3:13)
    at Module._compile (module.js:660:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:671:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:573:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:513:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:505:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:701:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:193:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:617:3
```

How should this be setup? How to integrate this best into Feathers? From [this](https://github.com/feathersjs/feathers/issues/313) I get the impression that Services & Hooks setup is preferable to a setup as middleware!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For reference, the solution from the [GitHub issue](https://github.com/feathersjs/feathers/issues/801) is to use `require('@feathersjs/express').original` or `require('express')` to initialize the application:

```
const createExpressApp = require('express');
const uploadApp = createExpressApp();

uploadApp.all('*', tusServer.handle.bind(tusServer));
app.use('/uploads', uploadApp);
```

Or by accessing require('@feathersjs/express').original (the express module @feathersjs/express relies on) in your app like this:

```
const uploadApp = express.original();

uploadApp.all('*', tusServer.handle.bind(tusServer));
app.use('/uploads', uploadApp);
```